# Fill form and visit webpage with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I want to input a string in this web page `http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gorf/orfig.cgi` and, after click `analyze` or something similar in an `HTML` (like clicking `OrfFind` in that webpage), get the output in a browser. Is that possible with `NodeJS`?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple tools/frameworks in different sizes that you can use. Basically the keyword you want to search for is end-to-end testing. Popular packages are [Zombie.js](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) or [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/).

According to the context you might also consider a headless browser that is scripted with javascript such as [Casper.js](http://casperjs.org/) or [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with NODEJS. [Nightwatch.js](http://nightwatchjs.org/)

Sample is below.

```
 module.exports = {
"Demo test Google" : function (client) {
   client
  .url("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gorf/orfig.cgi")
  .click("button[name=OrfFind]")
```